# Are the Taylor polynomials of a function the results of a minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, approximation

Here is an example to better explain my question.

Consider the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$. I want to approximate it in the set $[-\pi; \pi]$ using a polynomial $g(x) = a + bx + cx^2$ of order $2$.

**First approach - Taylor polynomials**

$$f(x) \simeq g(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} $$

**Second approach - Minimization of Euclidean Norm**

I look for $g(x)$ such that:

$$[a, b, c] = \arg \min_{a,b,c} \Phi(a,b,c),$$

where

$$\Phi(a,b,c) = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}[f(x)-g(x)]^2\text{d}x$$
I have to evaluate first derivative with respect to $a$, $b$ and $c$ and impose that they are $0$:

$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a} = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{\partial }{\partial a}[f(x)-g(x)]^2\text{d}x = -2\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}[f(x)-g(x)]\text{d}x = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial b} = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{\partial }{\partial b}[f(x)-g(x)]^2\text{d}x = -2\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}x[f(x)-g(x)]\text{d}x = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial c} = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{\partial }{\partial c}[f(x)-g(x)]^2\text{d}x = -2\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}x^2[f(x)-g(x)]\text{d}x = 0$$

At the end, I get:

$$g(x) = \frac{15}{2\pi^2} - \frac{45x^2}{2\pi^4}$$

**Other approaches**

One can use a different norm

**The question**

Are the Taylor polynomials of a function the results of a minimization problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how satisfying this answer will be, but here's something:

The $n$th degree Taylor (MacLaurin) polynomial $g(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ is the unique degree $n$ polynomial such that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{x^n}\right)^2 = 0
$$
Is there some corresponding quantity that has been minimized?  I'm not sure

Comment: Since the square is always non-negative, $0$ is the minimum (or infimum), doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, yes, it does!  Well there you go

Comment: The answer to a related question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978990/prove-that-the-taylor-series-is-the-solution-to-this-minimization-problem) implies that this is a very non-smooth optimization problem; I think the quantity above, viewed as a function of the coefficients of $g$, is infinity almost everywhere, and is $0$ precisely at the solution. I think it's continuous nowhere, so optimization as I know it doesn't apply at all, i.e., differentiating w.r.t. the polynomial coefficients and setting equal to zero gets you nowhere because those derivatives are undefined everywhere.