# Prove that the Taylor series is the solution to this minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965663/are-the-taylor-polynomials-of-a-function-the-results-of-a-minimization-problem) says that a MacLaurin polynomial of a function $f$ is the unique $N^\text{th}$ order polynomial that minimizes the following functional:

$$
L[g] = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^N}\right)^2,
$$
and that the minimum value attained is $0$,
$$
\min_{g} L[g] = 0
$$

I'm wondering if anyone has a reference for a proof of this fact in a forward sense, i.e., starting from the above, show that $g$ must be equal to the formula for the MacLaurin series of $f$, without directly invoking some form of Taylor's theorem to expand $f$. Basically, assuming we didn't know anything about Taylor/MacLaurin series or polynomials, can we derive them from the above minimization problem?

**Possible path**

We know $g$ is an $N^\text{th}$ order polynomial:
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n = \vec{X}\cdot\vec{a},
$$
where 
$$
\vec{X} = \left[1\;\; x\;\; x^2\;\;\ldots\;\;x^N\right]^\text{T},
$$
and 
$$
\vec{a} = \left[a_0\;\; a_1\;\; a_2\;\;\ldots\;\;a_N\right]^\text{T}.
$$
Now I know I'll need to know the sensitivities of that functional to the parameters:
$$
\nabla_\vec{a} L[g] = 
\left[
\frac{\partial L[g]}{\partial a_0}\;\;
\frac{\partial L[g]}{\partial a_1}\;\;
\frac{\partial L[g]}{\partial a_2}\;\;\ldots\;\;
\frac{\partial L[g]}{\partial a_N}
\right]^\text{T}
$$

And that through application of the chain rule, I'll also need that
$$
\nabla_\vec{a} g = \vec{X}.
$$
Setting the gradient of the functional w.r.t. $\vec{a}$ to zero for each component should give me a way to solve for $g$, I just don't see a clear path forward that results in the formula for a Taylor polynomial. I hope someone can illuminate the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(0) \ne g(0)$. Then the numerator of the limit is finite while the denominator goes to zero, so the limit diverges. Therefore, $L[g]$ can only be finite if $f(0) = g(0)$.

Apply L'Hôpital's rule and we have
$$L[g] = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f'(x)-g'(x)}{Nx^{N-1}}\right)^2.$$
By the same logic, for $L[g]$ to be finite we must have $f'(0) = g'(0)$.

Repeat $N$ times, obtaining the conditions $f(0) = g(0)$, $f'(0) = g'(0)$, $f''(0) = g''(0)$, ..., $f^{(N-1)}(0) = g^{(N-1)}(0)$, until finally
$$\begin{align}
L[g] &= \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f^{(N)}(x)-g^{(N)}(x)}{N!}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac1{N!}\bigl(f^{(N)}(0) - g^{(N)}(0)\bigr)^2,
\end{align}$$
which is clearly minimized at $f^{(N)}(0) = g^{(N)}(0)$. Therefore, $f$ and $g$ must have the same $0$th to $N$th derivatives.

Comment: I like this answer in that it certainly shows what I asked for; however, it proceeds by forcing $L[g]$ to be finite, not to be driven to $0$ according to the minimization problem. I was hoping for a solution that, by going through the steps of solving the minimization problem, ends up deriving the Taylor/MacLaurin series formulas.

Comment: Unfortunately one cannot do the usual thing of computing derivatives and setting them to zero because, as I showed, the objective is not defined in an open set around the minimum. Consider $f(x) = 1+x$ and $N=1$; then $$L[g] = \begin{cases}(a_1-1)^2 & \text{if $a_0=1$,} \\ \infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ What do you suppose $\partial L[g]/\partial a_0$ is?

Comment: I see, this is a particularly badly behaved objective function. The objective is infinite almost everywhere, correct? So it's not much better than an indicator function that gives a yes/no answer on the suitability of $g$. I wonder if there is some convex objective function (or at least locally convex around the solution with some smoothness away from the solution) that also has the Taylor polynomial as the minimizer. Perhaps this is another question in the making.

Answer (score 1):

Let us split the problem in two parts: the existence of the minimum, and its uniqueness. For simplicity, notice that we may significantly simplify the problem by replacing the square in $L$ with a modulus, because the functions $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto |x|$ have the same minimum, attained in the same point.

If $f$ admits derivatives up to (and including) order $n$ in $0$, let

$$T_{n,f} (x) = \sum _{k=0} ^n \frac {f^{(k)} (0)} {k!} x^k$$

be the $n$-th degree MacLaurin polynomial function of $f$.

Let $L_{n,f}$ be the (obviously positive) functional

$$L_{n,f} (g) = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - g(x)} {x^n} \right| $$

We shall show that $T_{n,f}$ is a minimum of the functional $L_{n,f}$ by induction on $n$.

For $n=0$ this is clear for every $f$:

$$L_{0,f} (T_{0,f}) = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - T_{0,f} (x)} {1} \right| = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - f(0)} {1} \right| = 0$$

so $T_{0,f}$ is a point of minimum for $L_{0,f}$.

For $n>0$, the induction hypothesis is that *for every $f$ having derivatives up to (and including) order $n$ in $0$, $T_{n,f}$ is a point of minimum for $L_{n,f}$*; we shall prove the same statement for $n+1$:

$$L_{n+1, f} (T_{n+1, f}) = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - T_{n+1, f} (x)} {x^{n+1}} \right| = \left| \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x) - T_{n+1, f} (x)} {x^{n+1}} \right| = \left| \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {f'(x) - T'_{n+1, f} (x)} {(n+1) x^n} \right| = \frac 1 {n+1} \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f'(x) - T_{n, f'} (x)} {x^n} \right| = \frac 1 {n+1} L_{n, f'} (T_{n, f'}) = 0 .$$

In words, the explanation of the above equalities:

- the second "$=$" is because the modulus function $x \mapsto |x|$ is continuous, so we may slip the limit inside and outside of it;
- the third "$=$" is an application of L'Hospital's theorem;
- the fourth "$=$" is because the derivative of $T_{n+1, f}$ is $T_{n, f'}$ (check it!)
- the fifth "$=$" is again by continuity
- the last "$=$" is by the induction hypothesis (notice that if $f$ has derivatives up to (and including) order $n+1$ in $0$, then $f'$ has derivatives up to (and including) order $n$ in $0$).

We have thus shown that for every $f$ having derivatives up to (and including) order $n+1$ in $0$, $T_{n+1, f}$ is a point of minimum for $L_{n+1, f}$, and this ends the proof by induction, therefore establishing that the MacLaurin polynomial functions are points of minimum for their respective functionals.

---

Let us now prove the uniqueness part. Let $g$, a polynomial function of degree $n$, be a point of minimum for $L_{n,f}$. Then

$$0 = L_{n,f} (g) = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - g(x)} {x^n} \right| = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - T_{n,f}(x) + T_{n,f}(x) - g(x)} {x^n} \right| \le \\
\underbrace{ \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {f(x) - T_{n,f} (x)} {x^n} \right|} _{= L_{n,f} (T_{n,f}) = 0} + \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {T_{n,f} (x) - g(x)} {x^n} \right| = \lim _{x \to 0} \left| \frac {T_{n,f} (x) - g(x)} {x^n} \right| .$$

To show that this implies $g = T_{n,f}$ we shall prove a more general result: *if $p$ is a polynomial function of degree $n$ such that $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {p(x)} {x^n} = 0$, then $p=0$*. Again, we shall use induction.

If $n=0$, then $p$ is a constant (for this problem I consider the $0$ polynomial to have degree $0$, for a uniform formulation of the proof), and it immediately follows that the only possible constant is $0$.

Assuming the result proven for $n$, then if $p$ has degree $n+1$ we may write (by L'Hospital's theorem, again):

$$0 = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {p(x)} {x^{n+1}} = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac {p'(x)} {(n+1)x^n} ,$$

which shows, according to the induction hypothesis, that $p' = 0$, so that $p$ must be a constant. Again, it is obvious that the only constant that works is $p=0$, and this ends our proof.

Applying now the above result to $p = T_{n,f} - g$ shows that $g = T_{n,f}$, so $T_{n,f}$ is the unique point of minimum for $L_{n,f}$.

Comment: A very nice answer, thank you. Both the existence and uniqueness arguments use the $T_{n,f}$ polynomial (trying it as a solution in one case, and adding and subtracting it as an intermediate step in the other case). Although I wanted a solution "assuming we didn't know anything about Taylor/MacLaurin series or polynomials", I fear that such an approach is not tractable in the framework used in your proof.